# What is the quickest way to upload my source code to a remote computer?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, rdp

Whats the quickest method to upload changes in local source code to a remote Windows PC?

FTP just doesn't cut it: it might take 2 minutes to create 100 tiny little files, whereas if these files were zipped up, transferred and then unzipped on the remote computer, it would take seconds.

Ideally, I want some solution that can:

- Zip up the changes that I've made to the source code tree (excluding certain file extensions such as *.pdb).
- Upload the zip to a remote PC.
- Let the remote PC unzip the changes into the source code directory.

Comment: You may want to look into Source Control and hosting for it.  See here: http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans

Comment: @Oded - what could be more on topic than synchronizing C# source code changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
Mercurial has an inbuilt Web Server.
These only push/pull changes.

Answer (score 1):

I depends what you can install on the remote windows pc. I like to use rsync which is essentially a unix utility, but you can run it on windows under cygwin. http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PowerShell script to zip the files, unzip them on the remote PC and any other processing required (eg update config files).

You could also run the script from a scheduled task if required to run periodically.